# How to Join two rows in one rows in result set for SQL and SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services

My current requirement is to get some interesting results. I am getting the result right but I have to do beautification of it, where I need your help PLEASE.

Here is the code followed by result and then followed by expected result.

```
    Select 
    a.owneridname As Name
   ,a.[serviceidname] As Service
   ,count(case
            when 
                a.[statuscodename] like 'Confirmed' or a.new_approvalstatusname like 'Approved'
            then
                a.serviceid
           end) As 'Total# Confirmed Activities'

    ,CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 16 ), 
            FLOOR( ( sum(case
            when
                a.serviceidname not like 'Indirect' and a.[statuscodename] like 'Confirmed' or a.new_approvalstatusname like 'Approved'
            then    
                a.[scheduleddurationminutes]
            end) ) / 60.0 ) ) 
            + N':' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 5 ), CONVERT( INTEGER, 
            FLOOR( (sum(case
            when
                a.serviceidname not like 'Indirect' 
            then    
                a.[scheduleddurationminutes]
            end)) % 60.0 ) )) as 'Total Direct Activites HH:MM'

     ,CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 16 ), 
            FLOOR( ( sum(case
            when
                a.serviceidname  like 'Indirect' and a.[statuscodename] like 'Confirmed' or a.new_approvalstatusname like 'Approved'
            then    
                a.[scheduleddurationminutes]
            end) ) / 60.0 ) ) 
            + N':' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 5 ), CONVERT( INTEGER, 
            FLOOR( (sum(case
            when
                a.serviceidname  like 'Indirect'
            then    
                a.[scheduleddurationminutes]
            end)) % 60.0 ) )) as 'Total Indirect Activites HH:MM'

    ,CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 16 ), 
            FLOOR( ( sum(case
            when
                a.[statuscodename] like 'Confirmed' or a.new_approvalstatusname like 'Approved'
            then    
                a.[scheduleddurationminutes]
            end) ) / 60.0 ) ) 
            + N':' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 5 ), CONVERT( INTEGER, 
            FLOOR( (sum(case
            when
                a.[statuscodename] like 'Confirmed' or a.new_approvalstatusname like 'Approved'
            then    
                a.[scheduleddurationminutes]
            end)) % 60.0 ) )) as 'Total Activites HH:MM'

    ,Sum(Case 
                when a.[statuscodename] like 'Confirmed' or a.new_approvalstatusname like 'Approved' and a.serviceidname not like 'Indirect'
                then
                    b.new_approvedmileage
                end
            ) as 'Total  Approved Mileage (KMs)'

    ,CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 16 ), 
            FLOOR( ( sum(case
            when
                b.new_expensestatusname like 'Approved'
            then    
                b.new_approvedtravel
            end) ) / 60.0 ) ) 
            + N':' + CONVERT( NVARCHAR( 5 ), CONVERT( INTEGER, 
            FLOOR( (sum(case
            when
                b.new_expensestatusname like 'Approved'
            then    
                b.new_approvedtravel
            end)) % 60.0 ) )) as 'Total Approved Travel Time HH:MM'

    ,count(Case 
                when b.new_expensestatusname like 'Approved' and b.new_expensetypeidname like 'Stipends'
                then
                     b.new_expensetypeidname
                end
            ) As 'Total #Approved Stipends'

from 
    [dbo].[FilteredServiceAppointment] a 
join
    [VEGA_MSCRM].[dbo].[FilteredNew_expenses] b
on 
    a.ownerid=b.ownerid
where 
    a.owneridname like 'Peter' and
    b.new_serviceactivityid is null 
group by
    a.owneridname
   ,a.[serviceidname] 

order by
a.owneridname
```

Here is what I get as result

```
Name      Service   Total# Confirmed Activities     Total Direct Activites HH:MM     Total Indirect Activites HH:MM  Total Activites HH:MM   Total  Approved Mileage (KMs)  Total Approved Travel Time HH:MM     Total #Approved Stipends
Peter   Indirect        1                                 NULL                                  0:21                             0:21           21                           0:21                                             0
Peter   Cooling         7                                 6:30                 .                NULL                             6:30           147                       .  2:48                                             0
```

What I want to join both of these rows and produce a single line result and I am just confuse.

Here is what result should look like.

```
Name           Service      Total# Confirmed Activities Total Direct Activites HH:MM    Total Indirect Activites HH:MM  Total Activites HH:MM   Total  Approved Mileage (KMs)   Total Approved Travel Time HH:MM    Total #Approved Stipends
Peter           Cooling           8                                 6:30                 .         0:21                          6:51                               21                           0:21                .          0
```

PLEASE HELP, since I am kind of confuse now where to make a change to get above expected result.

Thanks.

Comment: You're grouping your results by [serviceidname].  If you want the total regardless of the Service, then remove [serviceidname] from the GROUP BY statement and the SELECT statement.

Comment: I would like to keep service id name and just don't want any indirect as name of the service listed under service.

Comment: Then just use a WHERE clause and filter out the indirect

Comment: I would like to combine result of Cooling and Indirect service , but want to keep cooling and display 8(1 from indirect + 7 from cooling) , 6:30 from cooling, 0:21 from Indirect, 6:51 as total, 21 as approved mileage KMs, 0:21 as total approved travel time HH:MM

Comment: Hi EMUEVIL , thanks for respose but It will give me total confirmed activities as & only I want * because 1 is from Indirect.

Comment: If you want to roll the "Indirect" service results into another total, you need to specify which catagory they should fall under then use a CASE statement in your select and group by in order to lump them together.

Comment: You will have to explain the rules for what you want in each column.   They are not obvious.   For example in `Total Activities` you seem to want a sum (0:21 + 6:30), but in `Total Approved Mileage` you only want "21".   Why?

Comment: Hi Tab Alleman, 0:21 and 6:30 are HH:MM to do Indirect and Cooling service respectively. Total Approved Mileage is 21 which the mileage to reach to that destination to do these activities.

Comment: You can get the total for all rows under each user by just removing the Service from the GROUP BY clause.  But if you want only certain columns to be totaled and others to ignore indirect, we need more information about how you would like each column calculated.

Comment: Sure, I would love to provider all information that you need. So basically this is SSRS report, where user select stat and end date which corresponds to schedule start date and end date then Office(New York, Toronto, New Jersey) and then select service type(Cooling, heating)

Comment: Once provider goes to do service we calculate total no. of hours and minutes , few times provider has to go where it's not billable so we call it as indirect service. we count total number of confirmed activities during specit start and end date.

Comment: once he finished with the service appointment he confirms it and than manager approves it. provider also put mileage and travel time gets calculated by 1 min per 1 mile.

Comment: I guess it will now give you more understanding of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: If you don't want two results rows for only certain columns, you need to manually aggregate the date into one column yourself for each individual column in the select.  Do this by filtering within your `CASE` statements in order to exclude rows where `serviceidname = 'indirect'` for the columns that you don't want that data added to the sum.

Comment: hmm. let me try this. Or I am getting right result for Total confirmed SAs , Direct SAs, Indirect SA and it total. I am thinking to display them in a table in SSRS, and putting second table right beside it to display Total Mileage, Total Mileage HH:MM and Stipend. Hopefully it will look nice.